# JQuery Клонирование элемента

Tags: jquery

Есть такая строка

```
<p id="input-desc"><input type="text" name="var_desc[]" placeholder="Название параметра" required></p>
```

И есть кнопка для её клонирования, которая выполняет функцию

```
function clone_input(target)
{
        $(target).clone().insertAfter(target);
}
```

но она вставляет новый элемент после первого **input-desc**, как сделать, чтоб новый элемент добавлялся в конце?
И ещё чтоб в новой строке обнулялось значение **value**

Comment: добавлялся в конце (в конец) чего?

Comment: ниже **input-desc**, а потом новый элемент ниже только что добавленного элемента и т.д.

Comment: как вызывается эта функция `clone_input`? Что передается в качестве параметра?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

вообще, на мой взгляд, плохая идея плодить элементы с одинаковым `id`. я бы заменил `id="input-desc"` на `class="input-desc"`
и если тебе нужно, что бы новый элемент всегда вставлялся после последнего такого же
то
`$(target).clone().insertAfter(".input-desc:last");`

если тебе нужно что бы функция оперировала именно `target`,
то можно идти другим путем
вызывать ее как:
`clone_input('.input-desc:last')`
тогда твою функцию можно оставить без изменений, а если нужно, что бы еще и значение в поле  для ввода очищалось, тогда так:
`$(target).clone().insertAfter($(target)).find("input").val("");`

Comment: А в **insertAfter()** можно выразить **.input-desc:last** через **target**?

Comment: тут сложно сказать, ты же не показал как у тебя идет вызов функции и что именно будет в target. В общем случае, наверное, нет. Надо знать, что именно является `target`, если это `p`, тогда сработает `target.parent().find(".input-desc:last")`, если это `input`, тогда нужно будет `target.parent().parent().find(".input-desc:last")`

Comment: У меня изначально она вызывалась так **clone_input('#input-desc');**, но так как вы посоветовали изменить id на class, то теперь будет **clone_input('.input-desc');**. И как еще можно сделать, чтоб value input клонированного элемента было пустым?

Comment: подправил ответ

Comment: @lar1ch, передавай в функцию не селектор, а элемент, после которого надо вставить и проблемы с выбором не будет

Comment: принципиальной разницы нет. что передавать селектор и в функции обращаться `$(target)` либо передавать элемент и в функции обращаться просто `target`

Comment: @AndreyMaslov, есть разница - в первом случае будет происходить выборка, зависящая от селектора, во втором - есть конкретный элемент после которого произойдет вставка

Comment: согласен, что фактически перенести объект внутрь функции выглядит логичней и при дальнейшей поддержке и развитии проекта будет наглядней сам код функции